# How to remove ylabel from Seaborn histplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

This is what I have:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
sns.histplot(my_data, ax=ax)
ax.set(ylabel='')
```

But this still seems to allocate the space for the y-axis label, it's only that the label itself is an empty string, which results in wasted space on the left-hand side of the image. I don't want the white space in place of the y-axis label, I really want to remove it.

Comment: If you set the label spacing setting to 0, it will be closer to the left side as expected. `g=sns.histplot(...);g.set_ylabel('', labelpad=0)`

Comment: You can also try `plt.tight_layout()` which would adapt the spacing at the four sides.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers suggested in the comments work.

One way to achieve what I want is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
sns.histplot(my_data, ax=ax)
ax.set(ylabel='')
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
```

The `pad` parameter of `tight_layout` controls the size of the margin around the figure.